# Why Zsh terminal icons are not getting displayed in Atom Platformio Ide Terminal?

Tags: arch-linux, gnome, zsh, manjaro, atom-editor

[Screenshot of the faulty Atom Platformio Ide Terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yIiZe.png)

I'm running Atom on Manjaro Linux. And I installed Platformio Ide Terminal. Everything is working fine, except the Zsh shell icons. None of the icons is getting displayed. Only boxes like you can see in the screenshot. I'm running Gnome Desktop Environment. Everything is fine in Zsh shell I get in the gnome-terminal

Here is a screenshot of the same commands executed in gnome-terminal Gnome Terminal
[Screenshot of gnom-terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YMY7F.png)

What's wrong with the terminal in Atom? What can be donw to make it look like the gnome-terminal?

Answer (score 0):

The problem here was the Atom Platformio Ide Terminal was using a font that didn't include the icons that were being used in the Zsh shell.

All I had to do was to check which font was being used by `gnome-terminal` and apply it to Atom Platformio Ide Terminal. The option to change the font was there in the package settings. And I could see the font being used by `gnome-terminal` by going to **Preferences --> 'Active Profile name' --> Text**